# If statement variables and array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to dynamically show or hide an element based on the current site title. There are more than 4 pages but only using 4 as an example:

```
var stringTitle = window.location.pathname; 
var home1 = "/sites/xxx/pages/home.aspx";
var home2 = "/sites/xxx/employees/pages/home.aspx";
var home3 = "/sites/xxx/directory/pages/home.aspx";
var home4 = "/sites/xxx/forms/pages/home.aspx";

if (stringTitle == home1 || stringTitle == home2 || stringTitle == home3) {
    //Display Something
}
```

Since this could potentially be really long, is there a way I can use variables in array then use it in If statement? I tried the following but didn't work and also found out `includes()` doesn't work in IE:

```
var hmArray = [home1, home2, home3, ...];
var n = hmArray.includes(stringTitle); //true or false
if (n == 1) {
  //display stuff
}
```

Comment: [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) returns a boolean value.

Comment: You can still use `Array.includes` in IE. You just need to add the pollyfill so it'll work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Polyfill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`indexOf();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```
if (hmArray.indexOf(stringTitle) !== -1) {
  // display stuff
}
```

Comment: I tried `indexOf` before but I thought it didn't work -- found out in dev tools that Chrome was not displaying the changes made -- it took few refresh / clear cache to apply the changes.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could make a polyfill for includes if you wanted.

```
Array.prototype.includes = Array.prototype.includes || function(value){
    return this.indexOf(value) > -1;
};
```

Then the browsers that have contains would use the native one, and those that don't would use yours.